# Limits and scope of the Java Attach API

Tags: java, jvm, classloader, bytecode

As far as I understand the Attach API introduced in Java 6 allows inter-process modification of classes running in a target **JVM** by means of agents. My questions are:

1. Is this strategy limited to only the instrumentation of classes that have NOT been loaded yet by the target **JVM** ? and
2. Which are the limits of these transformations ?. For example, only the body of existing methods can be modified ?, or everything in the class definition could be changed ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. You can instrument both classes already loaded or to be loaded by intercepting them with a `ClassFileTransformer`. However if a retransformed method has active stack frames, those active frames continue to run the bytecodes of the original method. The retransformed method will be used on new invokes.
2. The redefinition/retransformation may change method bodies, the constant pool and attributes. The redefinition/retransformation must not add, remove or rename fields or methods, change the signatures of methods, or change inheritance. These restrictions maybe be lifted in future versions. The class file bytes are not checked, verified and installed until after the transformations have been applied, if the resultant bytes are in error this method will throw an exception.

The javadoc for the [Instrumentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/instrument/Instrumentation.html) interface contains most of the information you are asking about.

Comment: I see. It is a pitty it does not allow to add new methods. I was thinking in trying to add a new interface to the class definition, but if no addition of methods is possible this is not going to work :(. Do you think I should be able to do something like providing a certain implementation to existing abstract methods and change the class from abstract to non-abstract ?

Comment: That may be possible but I don't see how you are planning to use it. If it is an abstract class you have to create an instance of it somewhere. If you are creating the instance you can always dynamically generate a class extending the abstract one. You can have a custom class loader to load the bytes of the new class. No need to change the original.

Comment: hi @jdb, this is exactly what I am doing right now (using Javassist), but it is difficult to interact with other frameworks (such as Hibernate) with the technique of extending the original abstract class (given that both my library and Hibernate want to instrument the same set of classes). Hence my question about how I could modify the original class. Unfortunately, not being able to add new methods to the class is a strong limitation for me so the Attach API still does not look like the perfect solution :(

Comment: With some JVMs you can provide implementation for the native methods (by renaming the original). You may try that if the abstract thing does not work. It probably has more limitations but it is worth mentioning. `Instrumentation#setNativeMethodPrefix`.

Comment: Thanks, please let me know if you have any good pointers for this.